# Get the second last parameter in a url using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a url like this

```
http://example.com/param1/param2/param3
```

Please help me get the second last parameter using javascript. I searched and could only find regex method to find the last parameter. I am new to this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basic string operations:

```
> 'http://example.com/param1/param2/param3'.split('/').slice(-2)[0]
"param2"
```

Answer (score 8):

```
var url = 'http://example.com/param1/param2/param3';
var result= url.split('/');
var Param = result[result.length-2];
```

Demo Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/HApnB/

[Split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) - Splits the string into an array of strings based on the separator you mentioned

In the above , `result` will be an array that contains

```
result = [http:,,example.com,param1,param2,param3];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by:

```
document.URL.split("/");
```

Comment: Just another answers note, split returns an array, so he has to get the .length - 2 item.

Comment: @ronnyfm You are right, but I beleive that answers should give direction and force you to experiment not copy&paste

Answer (score 2):

```
var url='http://example.com/param1/param2/param3';
var arr = url.split('/');
alert(arr[arr.length-2]);
```

arr[arr.length-2] will contain value 'param2'. Second last value

Answer (score 2):

```
var url = "http://example.com/param1/param2/param3";

var params = url.replace(/^http:\/\/,'').split('/'); // beware of the doubleslash

var secondlast = params[params.length-2]; // check for length!!
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = "http://example.com/param1/param2/param3";
var split = url.split("/");
alert(split[split.length - 2]);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gE7TW/

The -2 is to make sure you always get the second last

Answer (score 1):

My favorite answer is the following from @Blender

```
  'http://example.com/param1/param2/param3'.split('/').slice(-2)[0]
```

However all answers suffer from the edge case syndrome. Below are the results of applying the above to a number of variants of your input string:

```
"http://example.com/param1/param2/param3"  ==> "param2"
"http://example.com/param1/param2"  ==> "param1"
"http://example.com/param1/"  ==> "param1"
"http://example.com/param1"  ==> "example.com"
"http://example.com"  ==> ""
"http://"  ==> ""
"http"  ==> "http"
```

Note in particular the cases of the trailing `/`, the case with only `//` and the case with no `/`

Whether these edge cases are acceptable is something you will need to determine within the larger context of your code.

Do not validate this answer, choose from amongst the others.

Answer (score 0):

Just another alternate solution:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'http://example.com/param1/param2/param3'
var path = a.pathname;

// get array of params in path
var params = path.replace(/^\/+|\/+$/g, '').split('/');

// gets second from last parameter; returns undefined if not array;
var pop = params.slice(-2)[0];
```